# How the variable in javascripts is treated on function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have a function that have certain variable in it for example

```
  var test = 3; 

  function looper(){

     var testing = 1;
     testing += testing;

  }

  for (var i=0;i<=10,i++){

     looper();

     alert(test);

  }
```

if this function is been called in a loop each will get testing value as 2 or it is updating to last executed value ? beside can i get the value of test variable passed into the function or need to pass it as parameter ?

Comment: `var` variables are function scoped.

Comment: dude first of all change your for (var i=0;i<=10,i++) you have a comma replace it with semicolon. And it will alert 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> beside can i get the value of test variable passed into the function
>   or need to pass it as parameter ?

Yes, try

```
   var test = 3; 
   function looper(testing)
   {
       testing += testing;
       return testing;
   }
   for (var i=0;i<=10,i++)
   {
       test = looper(test);
       alert(test);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `var testing = 1;` so even if looped will be always over and over firstly instantiated to `1`.

You should move it outside of the function scope:

```
  var testing = 3;  // NOT "test" but "testing"!!!!!

  function looper(){
      testing += testing;
  }

  for (var i=0;i<=10,i++){
       looper();
  }

  alert(testing);   // "testing", remember?
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable test is globally declared so the value 3 is displayed on alert.
Where as on every call to a function looper the variable testing is created without retaining previous value and assigned a value 1 in that way the value of testing is always 2 on function call.

Answer (score -2):

```
var test = 3; 
var testing = 1;

function looper(){
     testing += testing;
     return testing;
}
for (var i=0;i<=10,i++){
    test = looper();
    alert(test);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help , just to make sure i understand well to get latest calculated testing variable i should placed outside the function and JavaScript can easily read variable from outside functions